# carrierwave access to file only from one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have problem with carrierwave.

I need limit access to files only from one page, but without any users/register/etc. so i have idea to create cookies when someone go to website, then allow access to the file. But i dont have idea how i can do this. i found this https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To:-Secure-Upload in carrierwave documentation, but is it solution for my problem?

Comment: *"is it solution for my problem?"* - Have you given it a try? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: i try, but now only registered users have access to files
i need access for everyone who have link for page

Comment: i need advice which way i should choose :)